# OpenServer и 'not support shell-commands'?

Tags: php, shell, openserver

Сайт на `MODx Revo`, размещен на локалке `OpenServer`. Ставлю плагин на сайт и при выполнение плагина вылетает сообщение `Your server does not support shell-commands. Backup not possible.`

Перенес сайт на классический виртуальный хостинг - ошибка пропала.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить данную ошибку на `OpenServer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите поиск, первая же ссылка с ответом от разработчика.
https://ospanel.io/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2973

Самый простой вариант -- устанавливать linux (хотя бы в виде виртуальной машины), поднимать там локальный сервер, тот же LAMP, например, и использовать эту среду для отладки/разработки сайта.

Логично, что на хостинге все завелось. Там, в отличие от вашего десктопа, стоит серверная linux.

А вообще, дорабатывать сайт лучше в максимально похожей на продуктивную среде. И винда в этом плане -- плохой выбор.

Comment: Да, я видел инфу о том, что лучше линукс, но может все-таки найдется менее радикальный способ решить эту проблему...

Comment: Ну, если совсем горит, попробуйте работать, например, через FTPSync, плагин для Sublime Text. Создаете на хостинге ftp пользователя, размещаете сайт в любой папке на компьютере и настраиваете в ней (перетащив папку в Sublime) ftp-соединение. При сохранении файла он будет автоматически отправляться на хостинг. Результат сможете видеть там же. Костыли, но хотя бы что-то...

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду синхронизацию проекта на хостинге с компом? Но вопрос опять-же не в этом, а в том, как исправить проблему в рамках OpenServer...

Comment: Покажите плагин, который ставите. Сразу скажу, что с модх я знаком весьма поверхностно и без теплых чувств. Крайне сомневаюсь, что есть другие варианты. OSpanel  -- все равно костыль, веб-разработка не вызывает таких (и не только) проблем  под линукс. Иногда стоит попробовать один раз, чтобы не мучить себя в будущем. И да, проблема не в опен сервере, а в том, что вы на винде. Следовательно, копать стоит в сторону хакинга плагина, но это еще хуже, чем всё сказанное выше.

Comment: `BackupMODX` плагин. Опробовал MODx + плагин на линуксе у знакомого - все работает. Значит и в правду винда всему проблема... Спасибо за инфу!